# What implementation will be used for PagingAndSortingRepository in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm a bit confused with Spring Data JPA. Could anybody explain the following?

Let's imagine I have the interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

What exactly the implementation of `PagingAndSortingRepository` will be used in runtime?

And I need to put `@Transactional` annotation on class or methods that will be using this repository?

Comment: I suppose that it is `PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation for the methods declared in the `PagingAndSortingRepository` are defined in `SimpleJpaRepository`.

If all what you want to do within a transaction is handled by a single repository call you don't need any extra `@Transactional`, but typically you do want the transaction to cover more then one call or at least a load operation and the manipulation of an entity afterwards. In those cases you would typically use a method annotated with `@Transactional`. But you could also use for example a `TranactionTemplate` which can be nice for example in certain kind of tests.

Comment: updated the answer to cover the part about transactions.